# How to animate drawing a UIBezierPath in swift

Tags: ios, swift, animation, uibezierpath

Does anybody know how to animate the drawing of an UIBezierPath within a custom view? So it looks like the iPhone has picked up a pen and is drawing on the screen slow enough to see it.

just say I have a path like the following:

```
var bezierPath = UIBezierPath()
bezierPath.moveToPoint(CGPointMake(49.5, 14.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(106.5, 14.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(106.5, 14.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(106.5, 14.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(119.5, 26.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(106.5, 14.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(119.5, 14.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(119.5, 75.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(119.5, 38.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(119.5, 75.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(106.5, 88.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(119.5, 75.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(122.5, 88.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(49.5, 88.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(90.5, 88.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(49.5, 88.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(36.5, 75.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(49.5, 88.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(36.5, 89.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(36.5, 26.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(36.5, 61.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(36.5, 26.5))
bezierPath.addCurveToPoint(CGPointMake(49.5, 14.5), controlPoint1: CGPointMake(36.5, 26.5), controlPoint2: CGPointMake(35.5, 14.5))
UIColor.redColor().setFill()
bezierPath.fill()
UIColor.blackColor().setStroke()
bezierPath.lineWidth = 10
bezierPath.stroke()
```

This draws a rounded rectangle and is written inside the drawRect function of a custom class.

Does anybody know how to animate the drawing of this?

Answer (score 8):

You might consider using a [CAShapeLayer](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CAShapeLayer_class/index.html) and animating the `strokeEnd` property (you can use CABasicAnimation to control the details of the animation). [This post](http://oleb.net/blog/2010/12/animating-drawing-of-cgpath-with-cashapelayer/) has an example.